# How to show custom attributes in desciption tab

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I have two tabs in product details page 1.description 2. additional information.
I want to remove additional information tab and move its attributes to description tab.
I am using magento 1.8.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default the the Additional information tab it's because of the attributes configuration (show on products page must be marked as no if you don't want they to appear).

As for changing the tab is more complicated because it depends on you theme, if you have a public url we might be able to help with the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage your attributes,

```
Go to catalog->attribute->manage Attribute Sets
```

Then you will get the all attribute sets grid,
Where choose your attributes set which contains the additional information attributes,
then you will get the edit attribute set window. where you can manage your attribute sets, By drag and drop option

Hope This works.